# What is the best practice for saving and refreshing a place_id from google places api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

On google places documentation it says:

> "Best practise is to refresh your stored place IDs periodically, after 100 days for example. One strategy is to store the original request that returned each place ID. If a place ID becomes invalid, you can re-issue that request to get fresh results. These results may or may not include the original place."

I'm using `AutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions` to retrieve places and save the place_id for the selected place.

Which other field should i save for later "refreshing" of the place_id and what is the best method of "refreshing" a single `place_id`? (I assume not using the AutocompleteService)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the Documentation posted in your question you can store the request that returned the place_id. So one way would be saving the user input (text used to do the request to Autocomplete) for the giving place_id.

Another way would be saving the "description" field (in the predictions) for the giving place_id. As stated in the documentation "description is the matched prediction" and since is associated with the place_id. You can be sure that this field is associated with the place.

It seems that saving the description will work but in some (very specific) cases they also might be changed in the database, giving inaccurate results.

Saving input text (used in autocomplete request) is better suggested but this one needs to be a strong query. what I mean by this is:

for example if you want to save the place_id for Times Square, maybe with the input "times" you already get a predictions for it, but "times" itself is not a strong query, so better save "times square".

And make sure the query you saved always get you your desired place as first prediction.

Comment: I see, and then once i need to refresh the place_id, how should i use the "description" to retrieve the new place_id? What is the correct api to use for retrieving a place_id using a "description"?

Regarding the first option of storing the user input for the autocomplete, i think it's not a good solution since i would need to also store an indicator of which of the predictions the user chose to be able to retrieve the specific one, basically bringing me to your second option anyway.

Comment: since "description" is actually a prediction, you can use the same getPlacePredictions to find the place, this way you make sure that if the place_id change you still can find the "new" one. Geocoding could be another option but since the query needs to be well formated in order to get good results, i would go for the Autocomplete service.

Comment: so you're saying to use the autocomplete service with the full description and then using the first returned prediction? (which will most likely also be the only one)

Comment: yes, I could recreate the example with the same place_id as first prediction. try a few examples a verify it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have accepted it. However, since this problem should exist for any user of this api, i would expect a more defined method for refreshing those id's that would also appear in the docs.

Comment: I will consult experts and update if i find something else

Comment: checked with an expert and I updated answer, seems both cases works fine thou the first one is more recommended